# right limit and continuity

Tags: limits

Let $f: [ a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Assume also that the right derivative of $f$ at $a$ exists: that is , the limit

$\lim_{x \rightarrow a+} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

exists. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$ , there exists $x \in (a,b)$ satisfying

$\Big\vert \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} - f^{'}(x) \Big\vert < \epsilon $

(NOTE: I think we should not assume that $f^{'}$ is continuous!)

Comment: Are you assuming $f'$ a continuous function?

Comment: If $f$ isn't continuous, then $f'$ isn't defined everywhere.

Comment: $f$  is continuous

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Have you read the first line in the question?

Comment: I did. His note says "NOTE: I think we should not assume that f is continuous!". I was pointing out that $f$ not being continuous could lead to problems, which is why that assumption is there.

Comment: Where did this question come from?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for all $x\in (a,b)$ we have 
$$|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{\prime}(x)|\geq \varepsilon_0$$
Put $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. We have $\displaystyle (x-a)g^{\prime}(x)=f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$. Hence $g^{\prime}(x)\not =0$ on $(a,b)$. We know that a derivative verify the intermediate value theorem; hence $g^{\prime}$ has a constant sign on $(a,b)$. Suppose $g^{\prime}(x)>0$. Then $g$ is increasing; if $x>y>a$, we get $g(x)\geq g(y)$, and if $y\to ,a$, that $g(x)\geq f^{\prime}(a)$. We have also
$$f^{\prime}(x)-\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=|\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{\prime}(x)|\geq \varepsilon_0$$
This imply that for $x\in (a,b)$:
$$f^{\prime}(x)\geq \varepsilon_0+f^{\prime}(a)  \,\,(1)$$
As $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f^{\prime}(a)$ if $x\to a$, there exists $\alpha>0$ such that if  $a<x<a+\alpha$ we have
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<f^{\prime}(a)+\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$$ and a $c\in (a,x)$ such that 
$\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f^{\prime}(c)$. This gives, using (1):

$$f^{\prime}(a)+\varepsilon_0\leq f^{\prime}(c)\leq f^{\prime}(a)+\frac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$$
a contradiction. The same for $g^{\prime}(x)<0$ (or change $f$ to $-f$).

Comment: sorry, I couldnt understant ==> there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} < f^{'}(a) + \dfrac{\varepsilon_0}{2}$.... and ==> in the last equation, it should be $f^{'}(a)-\varepsilon_0 \leq f^{'}(c)$...?

Comment: @parco: See the edited answer and say if this answer your comment.